# How can I add a title to each subplot in an ImageGrid and a single xlabel/ylabel for the entire figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created the following figure using `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1`:

[image]

For some reason, however, my subplot titles aren't appearing.  How can I go about fixing this?

**Code:**

```
# import 
from mpl_tookits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

fig = figure(figsize=(20, 12), dpi=300)
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(3, 4), axes_pad=1, aspect=False)
for gridax, (i, sub) in zip(grid, enumerate(eyelink_data)):
    subnum = i + start_with

     # format data
    xdat = sub['x'][(sub['in_trl'] == True) & (sub['x'].notnull()) & (sub['y'].notnull())]
    ydat = sub['y'][(sub['in_trl'] == True) & (sub['x'].notnull()) & (sub['y'].notnull())]

    # plot
    gridax.hist2d(xdat, ydat, bins=[np.linspace(-.005, .005, num=1000), np.linspace(-.005, .005, num=1000)])
    gridax.plot(0, 0, 'ro')  # origin

    title('Subject {0} in-Trial Gaze'.format(subnum))
    xlabel('Horizontal Offset\n(degrees visual angle)')
    ylabel('Vertical Offset\n(degrees visual angle)')

show()
```

P.S.:  enjoy the [grid illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_illusion)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a title for each subplot, you can just use the title command for that axis.  Where you have:

```
title('Subject {0} in-Trial Gaze'.format(subnum))
```

Just write:

```
gridax.set_title('Subject {0} in-Trial Gaze'.format(subnum))
```

---

If you want one big `xlabel` and `ylabel`, you'll have to make a large `axes` object around your grid.  I'm no expert, but this should help:

[Multiple Subplots with One Axis Label](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Multiple_Subplots_with_One_Axis_Label)